# null is not an object (Evaluating 'RNOtpverify.getotp')

Tags: react-native

After installing react-native-otp-verify package into my react-native application when i am trying to run application it showing error:

> null is not an object (Evaluating 'RNOtpverify.getotp')

I just installed it not yet used in my code and i want to use it in future . I want to know what may be posibilities which causes this issue please help me out if anyone knows and i am beginner for react-native

Below is my package json

```
"react-native": "~0.61.4",
"react-native-otp-verify": "^1.0.3",
```

Comment: You need to read this one first [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: did you link it properly? `react-native link` or `cd ios && pod install` ?

Comment: I had linked it. It is working properly now